# Can I MPI_Test for an Ibarrier

Tags: mpi

In this code, all processes post a barrier, sleep a while for good measure, then first `Test` and then `Wait` for the barrier. The `Test` says no and the wait succeeds. A test should be like a non-blocking wait, so it should succeed. What am I missing?

```
  printf("[%d] posting barrier, then sleeping\n",procid);
  MPI_Request final_barrier;
  MPI_Ibarrier(comm,&final_barrier);
  sleep(2);

  int all_done_flag=0;
  MPI_Test(&final_barrier,&all_done_flag,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  printf("[%d] all done: %d\n",procid,all_done_flag);

  MPI_Wait(&final_barrier,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  printf("[%d] concluded\n",procid);
```

Comment: If I just do two `MPI_Test`'s in a row instead of one, the second one succeeds. Some googling led me to [Why does MPI_Iprobe return false when message has definitely been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20999299/491171) (4 years old now), could the answer there be it?

Comment: Do you do the two tests both before the wait? I tried two tests followed by a wait, and then the second test is still not true.

A test after the wait will succeed (that's what your link is doing: an Iprobe after a blocking Probe) but that's not interesting to me.

Comment: I used https://gist.github.com/ikirill/30118fc521144e0e7d71a066261cbdde. In that answer (not the question) it seems to me they used a busy-loop with only an Iprobe inside.

Comment: So part of the answer is that `Test` is a local operation: does only local testing without any interaction with other processes, while `Wait` is a non-local operation. Another aspect of the problem is "progress": MPI needs to be activated every once in a while for everything to progress as it should.